# how do i create a toast for an activity from inside a different class

Tags: java, android

I have a class separate from my activity and I want a toast that appears in that activity when a method is called from the class. how do i do that?

Here is the method from the class. 
I want the toast to be called in the `else if (counter < addSpend)` statement.

```
public void shipAdd()
{
    if(counter >= addSpend)
    {
        counter -= addSpend;
        new TimerClass(addTime,1000)
        {

            public void onFinish() {

                counter += addAmount;
                this.start();

            }
        }.start();
    }else if (counter < addSpend)
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a way to get the context of the activity. I suggest passing it as a parameter to the shipAdd method. Then `Toast.makeText(context, message, duration).show()` as usual.

Comment: in fact is the only leak-free solution, storing the context inside the class can be a recipe for disaster

Answer (score 0):

pass the context of activity through constructor of this class

```
Toast.makeText(context, yourMessage, length).show()
```